# "How to run already created WordPress website locally"?

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I can download the WordPress website which is already created. So, I need to run that website locally. Please let me know step by step.

Comment: Please let us know what issue you are experiencing. Do you have PHP and mysql running? Is your database set up on your local DB?

Comment: Yes, I can run a Wordpress website locally. But, I see this error: "Error establishing a database connection".

Comment: So on to question 3, `Is your database set up on your local DB?`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your setup but I'll give you a complete solution now and then we fix any problems afterward.

First thing you need to do is download a local WordPress hosting environment and set up a local host for the website. I prefer to use FlyWheel because it's the easiest so far. Other options include Laragon, XAMP, and WAMP.

After installing Flywheel and setting up a local install you download the "All In One WP Migrator" plugin on both the live website you want to run locally and the local website.

Once you use that to migrate the website to a local setup everything should be fine. If you have the error establishing database connection again I will tell you how to resolve that. It's pretty easy actually.